# Debian 8 Systemd fstab can't mount file system

Tags: debian, filesystems, fstab

Just upgraded to Debian 8. And system can't be booted because of this two lines in **/etc/fstab**:

```
/dev/data/server/    /data           ext4    defaults        0       2
/data/vmail /var/vmail  none    bind
```

Don't know why systemd can't automatically mount file systems. I can mount them with command line utils. With Debian 7 everything worked perfectly. **/dev/data/server** is LVM volume. But don't think it's relevant.

So how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#systemd-auto-mounts-incompat) for this particular error:

You should use `nofail` or `noauto` in your fstab to start up your system and fix your mounting-errors.

Comment: Problem was slash in the end of /dev/data/server.

Comment: Ah yeah, well...are you sure it worked beforehand? Strange

Comment: It worked .. With Debian 7.